# Button behind Surface / Imageview is clickable?

Tags: android, imageview, surfaceview

I have created a SurfaceView for displaying live-video in my application. While using the app a user of my app might get called by another user and when the called user accepts the call a new fullscreen fragment is created with a fullscreen preview of the caller and a small preview of the user who is being called. The small preview is a Surfaceview and the big videoscreen is an ImageView.

When I touch these views I can click the buttons which are in the fragment or the mainactivity (in which all fragments are loaded) below my videofragment and they work. So I load my video and I am able to click on the video, activating a button click in another fragment which is not visible.

My question is: How can I configure these views to **not respond** to those clicks / touches?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it bij putting empty clickListeners on the views.